# Select records from table if certain value exists, if not, select other records

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
projectName | info
--------------------
     all    | i1
     all    | i2
     all    | i3
     name1  | i4
     name1  | i5
     all    | i6
```

I have a query that checks the project name. If it exists in the table, I have to select only the information regarding that specific project. If it does not exist, I must get the information for 'all' projects.

For example, if I my entry is 'name1', my output should be:

```
i4
i5
```

If my entry is 'name2', my output should be:

```
i1
i2
i3
i6
```

Is there a way I can do this in a mysql query? I looked for examples but everything I found was about retrieving information from two different tables.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a MySQL query? This would probably be easier to do within your application.

Comment: @JeffersonLima I just got curious about it, actually. I'll do it within my application if I can't work this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT info
FROM mytable
WHERE projectName = 'name1'

UNION ALL

SELECT info
FROM mytable
WHERE projectName = 'all' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable
                  WHERE projectName = 'name1')
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/JJGAO38574)

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from projects
where projectName = case when exists (select * from projects where projectName = 'name1')
    then 'name1'
    else 'all'
end
```

Comment: but you are outputing the project name instead of project info

Comment: @dsharew I'm outputting all columns `select *`. You can still select any column you want from the table.

Comment: got it very nice solution